# Why do I have to pair my devices again after changing the Bluetooth adapter?

Tags: macos, usb, bluetooth

My computer runs Yosemite and has no working internal Bluetooth chip.

I therefore connect a Bluetooth adapter through USB.

Recently, this USB Bluetooth adapter broke. I bought a new one, and inserted that instead.

The interesting thing is that my previously paired devices still appear in a list, but they are not paired anymore. Instead, I get an option to pair them again.

[image]

My theory is that this happens because the USB Bluetooth adapter has some sort of ID number or something and that the devices are paired to *that*, not the computer itself.

Is this true? If yes, what is this ID number called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Bluetooth "thing", for lack of a better word, has a [unique identifier](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bluetooth-basics/how-bluetooth-works). If it didn't, devices wouldn't be able to differentiate from one another. Walk down the street with AirPods here in a month or two and without a unique device identifier, you would get everybody else's music/conversations/whatever coming through your AirPods as you got within ~30 feet of them.

Your paired devices are still in that list because your computer remembers devices that were previously paired to it.